# Upsert on a range

Tags: sql-server-2008, upsert

I'm aware of this:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM table WHERE pk = @pk)
BEGIN
   --Update
END
ELSE
BEGIN 
   --INSERT
END
```

But this works for one row. Let's say I have a table `min_max M` and a temp table `__MinMaxImport T`. I want to `INSERT` from T to M, but `UPDATE` when the pair `branch_no`/`product` already exists in M.

INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO min_max
    (user_no, branch_no, product, min_stock, max_stock)
SELECT
    @user_no, _branch_no, _product, _min_stock, _max_stock
FROM 
    traxs_temp..__MinMaxImport 
WHERE 
    session_id = @session_id
```

UPDATE:

```
UPDATE min_max SET
    date_time = GETDATE(),
    user_no = @user_no,
    min_stock = _min_stock,
    max_stock = _max_stock
FROM
    min_max M
    INNER JOIN traxs_temp..__MinMaxImport T ON T._product = M.product 
AND T._branch_no = M.branch_no
WHERE 
    session_id = @session_id
```

What is the best solution to do this? I read about `MERGE` but I'm not sure how to use it.

Comment: `MERGE` should be able to do it. It will take me a while to look up the syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) should be able to do it.

```
MERGE INTO min_max
USING
(
    SELECT
        @user_no AS _user_no, _branch_no, _product, _min_stock, _max_stock
    FROM 
        traxs_temp..__MinMaxImport 
    WHERE 
        session_id = @session_id    
) AS Src
ON
    (min_max.branch_no = Src._branch_no) AND
    (min_max.product = Src._product)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET 
    date_time = GETDATE(),
    user_no = Src._user_no,
    min_stock = Src._min_stock,
    max_stock = Src._max_stock
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN 
INSERT 
    (user_no, branch_no, product, min_stock, max_stock)
VALUES
    (Src._user_no,
    Src._branch_no,
    Src._product,
    Src._min_stock,
    Src._max_stock)
;
```

Comment: I have this error: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.`

Comment: It looks like `MERGE` was added in SQL Server 2008. What version do you use? Add a proper tag to your question.

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2008, but it seems to be caused by `COMPATIBILTY_LEVEL` by default to 90 and should be 100.

Comment: @ArthurRey, Yes, that definitely could be the reason. I'm using `MERGE` in 2008 and the database was created in 2008, so its compatibity level is 100. Those databases that were created in 2005 and then upgraded to 2008 may preserve their previous compatibility level, so you'll have to change that.

Comment: I changed `COMPATIBILTY_LEVEL` to 100 and it is now working fine.